# Deleting default document in IIS 10 gives error 502

Tags: c#, testing, webapi, iis-10, default-document

After VAPT testing of my project or server it is recommended to delete `default document`. But when i try to delete or disable default document in `IIS server` , all webapis and websites stops running and gives `Error 502 bad gateway`. Please help me to delete or disable default document without resulting any error.

Comment: Not sure what you changed, but FRT should help you dig further into the 502 errors, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: There are many reasons for Error 502 bad gateway, can you post more information about this error? sunch as requested url, error code.